# Quotienting a direct sum by one of its factors

Tags: ring-theory, modules

If we have a direct sum of $R$-modules. say $M_1\oplus M_2$ does it then follow that $(M_1\oplus M_2)/M_1\cong M_2$

This seems like it should be the case but I can't think of a way to prove it/counterexample?

I have it in the back of my head that it is not the case. Are there any conditions under which this is true?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the projection homomorphism $\pi_2:M_1\oplus M_2\to M_2$ given by $\pi_2(x,y)=y$.

Its kernel is $\{(x,0)\mid x\in M_1\}$ and is canonically isomorphic to $M_1$ (which is what you meant when you quotient by $M_1$ above).

Now apply the isomorphism theorem to see that the isomorphism you mention always holds.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, and is a consequence of the First Isomorphism Theorem. Can you find a homomorphism $\varphi:M_1\oplus M_2\to M_1$ such that $\ker\varphi = M_2$? Then you are done.